# Make a 2d array with 2 simple array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, 2d

I've been searching for hours for an error in my javascript's code but I really don't understand why this error occur.

So I have 2 array that I've get by using ajax and I want to merge them into an 2d array but this error happen :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

So this is my code :

```
var arrayCityAccident = new Array([]);

for(var i = 0; i < responseAccident.length; i++)
{
arrayCityAccident [i][0] = responseCity[i]['city'];
arrayCityAccident [i][1] = responseAccident[i];
}
```

I've look up to see if my both 1d array have values and yes they have values so if someone could help me it will help me a lot.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new array to `arrayCityAccident` for each index `i`:

```
var arrayCityAccident = [];

for(var i = 0; i < responseAccident.length; i++)
{
    arrayCityAccident.push([responseCity[i]['city'], responseAccident[i]]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works ! Thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Well, as soon as `i` becomes bigger than 0 in your loop, `arrayCityAccident[i]` doesn't return an array anymore. You *only* defined `arrayCityAccident[0]`, so accessing `arrayCityAccident[i][0]` isn't possible.

Just add another array to `arrayCityAccident` before defining its elements:

```
var arrayCityAccident = new Array([]);

for(var i = 0; i < responseAccident.length; i++)
{
    arrayCityAccident[i] = []; // add a new array to arrayAccident
    arrayCityAccident[i][0] = responseCity[i]['city']; // now you can set those properties
    arrayCityAccident[i][1] = responseAccident[i];     // without problems
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "bigger than 0". However, this is more of a comment than an answer: you explain _why_ the error occurs, but don't address what to do about it.